# How to show that two integers with a sum of zero have one's complement representations that are bit-complementary?

Tags: c, math, binary, ones-complement

I've been stuck on this question for a while now:

Show mathematically that two integers that have a sum of zero have one’s complement representations that are bit-complementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple proof and a counter example:

One's complement representation by definition represents negative values with bit-complement. In other words `-n` is represented as `~n`. If any two integers have a sum of zero, either they are both zero or one is the opposite of the other.

- if they are both zero, they do not necessarily have one’s complement representations that are bit-complementary.
- if they are opposite of each other and non-zero, then yes, they are bit-complementary of one another.

Comment: I understand your proof and it does make sense, but I'm not sure how I can show mathematically:

5 + (-5) = 0

5 = 5

0101 = 0101

1010 (one's complement) = 1010 (one's complement)

I'm pretty sure this is completely wrong but it's where I'm at right now...

Thank you very much btw!

Comment: @cinos: There is not much to show mathematically. By definition, if the binary representation of a positive x is some string of bits s, then the one’s complement representation of −x is ~s (the string of bits in which each bit is the complement of the corresponding bit in s). So, for numbers other than zero, x and −x are **defined** to have complementary bit representations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ahhh I understand it now, thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @cinos: note however that `0+0=0` is a counter-example.